# What type of headers should use for http delete in angular 4

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm working with angular 4 and asp.net web api. in angular project i'm using a delete method to call web api delete method.when i'm using headers like below it works properly in locally.but after iis hosting it is not working.can i know what is the reason for that.

```
deleteItem(id) {
//debugger;
let headers = new Headers({    
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',


});
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http
  .delete(this.baseUrl + 
'BureauStateWorkflowSettings/DeleteBureauStateWorkflowSettingsById/'+id,{ 
headers: headers })
  .map((res: Response)=> this.flashMessage.show(res.text(),{ cssClass: 
'alert-success' }))
  .catch(this.handleError);


}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you explain more how it is no working? Do you see an error in the console? Or does it just not delete?

Comment: the error in console is No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access

Comment: This error means that your asp.net Web API is not set up to allow cross site scripting (meaning receiving requests from a URL that is not the same as the Web API). You can modify the Web API to allow access. But if you have deployed the app to the server ... the origin should no longer be localhost?

Answer (score 0):

You have not use RequestOptions

```
deleteItem(id) {
//debugger;
let headers = new Headers({    
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',


});
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http
  .delete(this.baseUrl + 
'BureauStateWorkflowSettings/DeleteBureauStateWorkflowSettingsById/'+id, options)
  .map((res: Response)=> this.flashMessage.show(res.text(),{ cssClass: 
'alert-success' }))
  .catch(this.handleError);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create header below format on delete request

const headers = new Headers({
                              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                           });

and send with your URL.

Answer (score 0):

> when i'm using headers like below it works properly in locally.but
>   after iis hosting it is not working

Looks like you use the same `baseUrl` to remote server. Change your `baseUrl` depending where application is running.

constants.ts:

```
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';

export const API_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('app.api-url');

export function API_URL_FACTORY() {
    if (environment.type === 'dev') {
        return 'http://8.8.8.8';
    } else {
        // debug...
        return 'http://localhost:60968';
    }
}
```

And register it `AppModule` providers:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
       ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
    entryComponents: [
    ],
    providers: [        
        <FactoryProvider>{
            provide: API_URL,
            useFactory: API_URL_FACTORY
        },
...
```

And you can inject it in contructor of service/component:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {

  constructor(
    @Inject(API_URL) private readonly apiUrl,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

}
```